# How to check ID uniqueness in list?

Tags: c#, oop

I have class `Person` and `PersonList`. If someone tries to add person with same id it should throw exception. I tried to override `Equals()`method but it doesn't checks id in children list.

For example:

```
Person father = new Person(id: 1);
father.Children.Add(new Person(id: 1));'
```

This should throw exception because person with id 1 already exists.

```
    class Person {
        public int ID { get; private set; }
        public PersonList Chilren { get; set; }

        public Person(int id) {
           Chilren = new PersonList();
           this.ID = id;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj) {
           return this.ID == (obj as Person).ID;
        }
    }

    class PersonList : List<Person> {
       new public void Add(Person person) {
           if (Contains(person)) {
               throw new Exception("Person already exists!");
           }
           base.Add(person);
       }
    }
```

Comment: For starters, you would also have to check the Children list manually with your approach. Is there anything that would prevent you from using a different data structure, namely one that implements Set (ie, can you use HashSet<T>? Sets are specifically designed to prevent the insertion of duplicates.

Comment: If you want to check for a unique ID, check for a unique `person.ID` rather than check for a person object - the answer is in the question. Rather than throwing from the collection class after the fact, have the class calling add check the value first.  Also, inheriting from `List` is ill advised, see [Guidelines for Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections)